# Makefile syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: shell, makefile

### Run for all the PROC to be executed.

```
## Run for all the proc to be executed.
$(PROC):
        @if [ -a $(TEST_DIR)/$@.c ]; then \
        $(info $(TARG) );\
        $(info $(CSEED) );\
        $(info "------------------");\
        $(info "COMPILING bin dir is $(BIN_DIR)");\
        $(MKDIR) $(BIN_DIR);\
        $(COPY) $(TEST_DIR)/*.c $(BIN_DIR) || true;\
        fi; \
```

I am getting below error for this piece of code. Trying to understand what I am missing here.

/bin/sh: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `;;' /bin/sh: -c: line 3:` ;'
make: *** [dp_hs0] Error 1
child process exited abnormally

Tried few changes but no luck

Comment: Please format the error message you're getting as a code block so it's readable.  Also please be sure to specify the OS you're using and the version of make you're using.

Comment: OS version
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.8 (Maipo)"

Make version
GNU Make 3.82

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have problems with makefiles, and particularly when you get shell syntax errors from your recipes, the very first thing you must do is remove the `@` prefix from your recipes.  Leaving it there is like sending all your compiler error messages to `/dev/null` then trying to figure out what's wrong with your program.

In your situation, you have to remember that `$(info ...)` is a make function, not a shell operation.  That means make will expand that function and replace it with the empty string.  So this:

```
    @if [ -a $(TEST_DIR)/$@.c ]; then \
    $(info $(TARG) );\
    $(info $(CSEED) );\
    $(info "------------------");\
    $(info "COMPILING bin dir is $(BIN_DIR)");\
    $(MKDIR) $(BIN_DIR);\
    $(COPY) $(TEST_DIR)/*.c $(BIN_DIR) || true;\
    fi; \
```

expands to this:

```
    if [ -a dir/prog.c ]; then \
    ;\
    ;\
    ;\
    ;\
    mkdir dir;\
    cp test/*.c dir || true;\
    fi; \
```

If you run that at the shell prompt you'll get the same error.  That's because the shell removes the backslashes and comes up with:

```
    if [ -a dir/prog.c ]; then ;;;;mkdir dir;cp test/*.c dir || true;fi;
```

and `;;` is a special character token to the shell (it's the ending of a `case` statement), so this is a syntax error.  Even if it wasn't, you can't have two semicolons in a row without a command; type this at your shell prompt:

```
$ ; ;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

You should remove the semicolons after the `$(info ...)` functions.

But, most likely you don't want to use `$(info ...)` here at all and you should just use `echo`.  That's because all make functions are expanded before the command is sent to the shell, which means that you will see this output even if your if-statement is false; since you included the `info` "inside" the if-statement I suppose you only wanted to see that output if the if-statement was true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

$(CORES):
        if [ -a $(TEST_DIR)/$@.c ]; then \
        $(info $(TARG) )
        $(info $(CSEED) )
        $(info "------------------")
        $(info "COMPILING bin dir is $(BIN_DIR)")
        $(MKDIR) $(BIN_DIR);\
        $(COPY) $(TEST_DIR)/*.c $(BIN_DIR) || true;\
        fi; \

Modified as per your comments and now I am getting below error.

/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [dp_hs0] Error 1
child process exited abnormally

Comment: We can't debug a problem based on comments where the newlines etc. are all missing.  Either edit your question and put the changed makefile in it (formatted as a code block) along with the error message (also formatted properly) or else ask a new question.